# ZF2: How to pass parameters to forward plugin which I can then get in the method I forward them to?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-routing

I have an Action method in **Foo** Controller which requires parameters:

```
public function fooAction($one, $two) {
    $a = one;
    $b = $two;
}
```

And I need to forward to that method from the other method of some **Boo** Controller. And one of those parameters has to be by reference parameter. The only example that [the manual](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-forward-plugin) has is this:

```
$result = $this->forward()->dispatch('Boo\Controller\Boo', array('action' => 'boo'));
```

No any additional parameters. But they write:

> $params is an optional array of parameters with which to see a
>   RouteMatch object for purposes of this specific request.

So, I tried:

```
$result = $this->forward()->dispatch('Boo\Controller\Boo', array(
                                                      'action' => 'boo',
                                                      'one' => &$one,
                                                      'two' => $two,
                                                 ));
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any way to pass additional parameters to forward controller?

**UPD:**

These do not work too:

```
$result = $this->forward()->dispatch('Boo\Controller\Boo', array(
                                                      'action' => 'boo',
                                                      'params' => array(
                                                          'one' => &$one,
                                                          'two' => $two,
                                                     )));


$result = $this->forward()->dispatch('Boo\Controller\Boo', array(
                                                      'action' => 'boo',
                                                      'options' => array(
                                                          'one' => &$one,
                                                          'two' => $two,
                                                     )));
```

**UPD 2:**

I still can't get the functionality I want (to pass parameters with the `forward` plugin) but I found other solutions. Before calling the `forward` plugin I set the variables to the `Request` object and after the `forward` I get them from the `Request` in my **boo** Action of my **Boo\Controller\BooController**:

```
// in Foo::fooAction
$this->getRequest()->one = &$one;
$this->getRequest()->two = $two;
$result = $this->forward()->dispatch('Boo\Controller\Boo', array('action' => 'boo'));

// in Boo::booAction
$a = $this->getRequest()->one;
$b = $this->getRequest()->two;
```

Stupid solution, it will not work with Ajax requests. Still interested how to pass parameters with the forward plugin. OR MAYBE how to get them in the **booAction**. Because there in no anything in the `Request` if I pass them with the `forward`.

**UPD 3 and Final:**

I finally found where they've decided to hide parameters I pass with the `forward` plugin. They put them in the `RouteMatch` object.

- Tryyyy to guess where we've hidden your params... Oh yeeah, they are in the `RouteMatch`, of course they are there, didn't you think smth else?

And NO ANY info in the `forward` plugin section of the manual!

To get params, I have to do this in my `BooController::booAction`:

```
$param = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('nameOfParam');
```

Comment: is `Boo` a valid Controller-Alias? As pointed out by the documentation `Boo` needs to be either a fully qualified ClassName (e.g.`Mymodule\Controller\BooController`) or it should be an alias to this controller which you define inside your configuration

Comment: Yes, it's a fully qualified ClassName, it is `'Boo\Controller\Boo'` I have. I wrote like this in the question to make it shorter. Change now to avoid obscurity.

Comment: This still is only an alias. It's safe to assume you've set up an invokables alias from `Boo\Controller\Boo` => `Boo\Controller\BooController` ? Other than that your first approach is the right one. How do you test if the params are present? Are they defined in route-configuration, too? Tihs blogpost uses the functionality you're looking for a lot: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a container class and use it in both controllers

in module.conf

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'my_handy_container'        => 'path\container_class_name',
        )
    );
}
```

Create a getter in both controllers:

```
public function getMyHandyContainer()
{
    if (!$this->myHandyContainer) {
        $this->myHandyContainer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my_handy_container');
    }
    return $this->myHandyContainer;
}
```

And call it using:

```
$myContainer = $this->getMyHandyContainer()->myHandyContainer;
$myContainer->foo = 5; // set something
```

## ZF2 way to pass vars using forward

In the passing method do:

```
return $this->forward()->dispatch('controller_name', [
    'action' => 'whatever',
    'varname' => $value,
    'varname2' => $value2
]);
```

In the invoked controller method, do:

```
$param2 = $this->params()->fromRoute('varname2',false);
```

Answer (score 12):

Why not to use the params plugin?

This works for me:

```
public function indexAction() {

        $object = new SomeObject();

        return $this->forward()->dispatch('Application\Controller\Index', [
                'action'     => 'show',
                'myObject'   => $object,
        ]);
    }

public function showAction() {

        $object = $this->params('myObject');

        var_dump($object);

        return [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would add another option that works for me.

You can simply pass the params straight through the forward function and use the routeMatch function to access them at the other end.

```
return $this->forward()
            ->dispatch('Module\Controller\Foo', array(
                                            'action' => 'bas', 
                                             'id' => 6)
                                              );
```

Passes to **Foo** Controller, **basAction** in this method you can then use the following code to access the id param

```
$myParam = (int) $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
```

Not sure if this meets your requirements - but works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question, helped me a lot. Found an easy way for getting all params passed to forward()->dispatch(...). In the controller's action method:

```
$params = $this->params()->fromRoute();
```

returns array $data as passed as $data into forward()->dispatch($controllerName, $data).

Answer (score 1):

[Here in the official ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#forward-plugin) is written exactly how it works:

*`$params` is an optional array of parameters with which to seed a RouteMatch object for purposes of this specific request. Meaning the parameters will be matched by their key to the routing identifiers in the config (otherwise non-matching keys are ignored)*.

So pass like this:

```
$params = array(
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'bar' => 'bar'
);
$this->forward()->dispatch('My\Controller', $params)
```

And then you can get your route match params in your `My\Controller` like normally:

```
$foo = $this->params()->fromRoute('foo');
$bar = $this->params()->fromRoute('bar');
```

For people struggling with accessing parameters within their controller here a nice overview from **[this CheatSheet](http://zf2cheatsheet.com/)**.

```
$this->params()->fromPost('foo');  //POST
$this->params()->fromQuery('foo'); //GET
$this->params()->fromRoute('foo'); //RouteMatch
$this->params()->fromHeader('foo');//Header
$this->params()->fromFiles('foo'); //Uploaded file
```