# ZF2: How to change Request object globally for all Controllers when using forward plugin?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, laminas-api-tools, zend-framework-routing

I'm using forward plugin in testing and performance purposes.
At first `IndexController` data passes through normal POST request.
There I get this requst and POST data and I need add one more parameter to it.

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()->subsystem = 'avia';
```

Than I use forward plugin

```
$result = $this->forward()->dispatch(
        "Port\\Controller",
        [
            'controller' => 'Port\\Controller',
            'action'     => 'port',
        ]
    );
```

And whan I'm in this `PortController` I would get my request POST data again and it SHOULD contain my changes from `IndexController`

```
$post              = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
isset($post['subsystem']) //true
```

But it does't. It get's request object without changes.

```
isset($post['subsystem']) //FALSE
```

How to change Request globally for all controllers in current request process?

**What i'm already trying?**

```
        //#1
        $params = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('params');
        $params->getController()->getRequest()
               ->getPost()->subsystem
                = 'avia';

        //#2
        $this->getRequest()->getPost()->subsystem = 'avia';

        //#3
        $post              = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $post['subsystem'] = 'avia';
        //NEED UPDATE GLOBALLY !
        $this->getRequest()->setPost($post);

        //#4
        $event                                     = $this->getEvent();
        $event->getRequest()->getPost()->subsystem = 'avia';
        Debug::vars($event->getRequest()->getPost());

        //#5
        $_POST = $post->toArray();
```

And all this variances not working.

**I'm already read this answer**
[ZF2: How to pass parameters to forward plugin which I can then get in the method I forward them to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766039/zf2-how-to-pass-parameters-to-forward-plugin-which-i-can-then-get-in-the-method)

But I don't want pass data through params, I need change Request.

**UPD**

But now i'm tested and maybe it was because on receiver side I tried to get request this way

```
 $request = $this->bodyParams();
```

But I should use it like this

```
if (!$request['subsystem']) {
      $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray();
 }
```

It was because I used Apigility RPC service and placed post data in JSON format in Request Content field, not in POST. And in another place I tried get it

```
$params         = $this->serviceLocator->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('params');
        $requestContent = $params->getController()->getRequest()->getContent();
        $request        = Json::decode($requestContent, Json::TYPE_ARRAY);
```

But after I started to use POST and that's why it started to be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is really something you should do but I think you should be able to achieve it like this:

```
$parameters = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$parameters->set('subsystem', 'avia');
```

`$parameters` is instance of `Zend\Stdlib\Parameters`.

Comment: Please, read my post again. I'm already do the same thing and it's not working. In `PortController` that I dispatched, when I get Request inside controller, field `subsystem` would be empty.

But now i'm tested and update my question.

Comment: It could be that "normal" *ZF2* solutions don't work for Apigility since there is much more going on. You should definitely mention the use of Apigility in your future questions. Apigility adds a lot of additional logic to the normal ZF2 request process.